# Why does tslm produce 11 seasons from the Seatbelts built in dataset?

Tags: r

I'm just learning R. I'm trying to use [tslm](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/forecast/docs/tslm) to construct a linear model based on the [Seatbelts](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/datasets/UKDriverDeaths) dataset. Here's what I tried:

```
tsdk<-Seatbelts[,"DriversKilled"]
require(forecast)
tslm(tsdk ~ season + trend)
```

Output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = formula, data = "tsdk", na.action = na.exclude)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      season2      season3      season4      season5      season6  
   136.0424     -13.3326     -13.4778     -14.7479      -8.7056      -4.1007  
    season7      season8      season9     season10     season11     season12  
    -3.4958      -4.3910       4.6514      21.7563      31.4861      39.2785  
      trend  
    -0.1674
```

Why are the seasons numbered 2-12? `frequency(tsdk)` is 12, so I'd expect there to be 12 seasons, one for each month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tslm is a time series linear model. Like a factor in a linear model, the seasons start with a baseline season, a.k.a. season 1. So if all the other seasons are 0, the default is season 1.